# C# static methods & attributes: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, static-methods

I'm using static methods and attributes, when I call a static method, I get a `NullReferenceException`.

sample class:

```
internal class Utils
{
    private static Regex[] _allRegexes = { _regexCategory };
    private static Regex _regexCategory = new Regex(@"(?<name>c(ategory){0,1}):(?<value>([^""\s]+)|("".+""))\s*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    public static string ExtractKeyWords(string queryString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queryString))
            return null;   

        _allRegexes[0];//here: _allRegexes[0]==null throw an exception
    }
}
```

cause:

> _allRegexes[0]==null

I can't figure it out why this happens, I think `_allRegexes` should be initialized when I call that method.

Can anybody explain it?

Comment: allRegexes by itself isn't a valid statement...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static fields get initialized in declaration order. This means `_regexCategory` is `null` when you initialize `_allRegexes`.

> The static field variable initializers of a class correspond to a sequence of assignments that are executed in the textual order in which they appear in the class declaration.

*(Quoted from C# Language Specification Version 4.0 - 10.5.5.1 Static field initialization)*

This leads to `_allRegexes` becoming an array that contains a single `null` element, i.e. `new Regex[]{null}`.

This means you can fix your code by putting `_regexCategory` before `_allRegexes` in your class.

Comment: sorry for that..It was in chaos..haha..actually I ans the same thing but was `downvoted`..?

Comment: what if add a static constructor??

Comment: @Kevin The static constructor will run after the fields get initialized. The field initializers with still run in textual order.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
    private static Regex _regexCategory = new Regex(@"(?<name>c(ategory){0,1}):(?<value>([^""\s]+)|("".+""))\s*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    private static Regex[] _allRegexes = { _regexCategory };
```

In your code the `IL` will load `_regexCategory` into `_allRegexes`  which is `NULL` because  the IL had never `initialized` it..

It `initalizes` when you instantiate `_regexCategory` with **new** keyword

Answer (score 1):

This code works without NRE

```
internal class Utils
{
    private static Regex _regexCategory = new Regex(
        @"(?<name>c(ategory){0,1}):(?<value>([^""\s]+)|("".+""))\s*", 
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    private static Regex[] _allRegexes = { _regexCategory };


    public static string ExtractKeyWords(string queryString)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queryString))
            return null;

        //change it to your needs, I just made it compile
        return _allRegexes[0].Match(queryString).Value;
    }
}    

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string result = Utils.ExtractKeyWords("foo");
    }
}
```

I believe the problem is in the order in which parameters are getting initialized.